# Kaggle Dataset Download

Tags: kaggle

Although I'm logged in my Kaggle Account (in Firefox), I simply cannot download any datasets from a certain past competition. No download button or the like is offered. Could it be that certain datasets are NOT downloadable? Kaggle itself doesn't offer a direct contact possibility - only a Q&A section.
Thx for any hints.

Comment: can you tell for example which dataset ?

Comment: Keeping the issue that *this question doesn't belong here* aside, last I checked they need your Phone Number associated with account if you want to download. Also it's possible that the specific competition's organizer may have opted to keep data-set private. This can happen if competition is limited to some internal groups (college, school etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down on the page for dataset

You should see a download button on the upper right hand side of the dataset file preview

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I needed to accept the rules of the competition first, then Kaggle sent me a validation code on my mobile, et voilà the data files were downloadable. Thanks to everypne who showed interest.